# null value for custom property aspects in alfresco 4.2e

Tags: java, alfresco

I am trying to insert document with **custom property** in **java** using **Alfresco 4.2e**. Now values are inserting without any error, but value for custom property is not set, it is showing null.

This my code:

```
    Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    props.put(PropertyIds.NAME, newDocName);
    props.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document,P:kb:referencable");
    props.put("kb:documentRef", "123");
    props.put("kb:documentID", "1234");
    String content = "sample=================";
    byte[] buf = null;
    try {
        buf = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    ContentStream contentStream = session.getObjectFactory()
            .createContentStream(newDocName, buf.length,
                    "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", input);
    target.createDocument(props, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
```

Serach query:

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM kb:referencable ";
    ItemIterable<QueryResult> queryResult = session.query(query, false);
    for (QueryResult item : queryResult) {
         System.out.println("item="+item.getProperties());

    }
```

Here is the search output:

```
item=[Property [id=kb:documentRef, display Name=KB Reference, local name=documentRef, query name=kb:documentRef, values=[]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:objectTypeId, display Name=Object Type Id, local name=objectTypeId, query name=cmis:objectTypeId, values=[cmis:document]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:lastModifiedBy, display Name=Last Modified By, local name=lastModifiedBy, query name=cmis:lastModifiedBy, values=[admin]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:name, display Name=Name, local name=name, query name=cmis:name, values=[chemistryTest1.txt]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:createdBy, display Name=Created by, local name=createdBy, query name=cmis:createdBy, values=[admin]][extensions=null], Property [id=kb:documentID, display Name=kb:documentID, local name=documentID, query name=kb:documentID, values=[]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:objectId, display Name=Object Id, local name=objectId, query name=cmis:objectId, values=[149666ab-5745-4365-b63e-c26cb6f4f6cc;1.0]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:creationDate, display Name=Creation Date, local name=creationDate, query name=cmis:creationDate, values=[java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+05:30",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2015,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=?,HOUR=?,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=32,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=725,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:changeToken, display Name=Change token, local name=changeToken, query name=cmis:changeToken, values=[]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds, display Name=Secondary Object Type Ids, local name=secondaryObjectTypeIds, query name=cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds, values=[P:kb:referencable, P:cm:titled, P:cm:author, P:sys:localized]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:baseTypeId, display Name=Base Type Id, local name=baseTypeId, query name=cmis:baseTypeId, values=[cmis:document]][extensions=null], Property [id=alfcmis:nodeRef, display Name=Alfresco Node Ref, local name=nodeRef, query name=alfcmis:nodeRef, values=[workspace://SpacesStore/149666ab-5745-4365-b63e-c26cb6f4f6cc]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:description, display Name=Description, local name=description, query name=cmis:description, values=[]][extensions=null], Property [id=cmis:lastModificationDate, display Name=Last Modified Date, local name=lastModificationDate, query name=cmis:lastModificationDate, values=[java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+05:30",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2015,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=?,HOUR=?,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=32,SECOND=59,MILLISECOND=725,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]]][extensions=null]]
```

Here value for kb:documentRef and kb:documentID (custom property)is null.

Comment: what does it mean? This code will create new node with name value as it was value of the `newDocName` variable but you won't see custom properties? did you made check with Node Browser?

Comment: @Miki :yes.custom properties won't see. I check with Node Browser, there aspect is present but my custom property is not listed. I updated my question with result of search query.

Comment: could you post your content model?

Answer (score 1):

Well, honestly I don't know if kb:documentRef is parsed as a shorthand, but the passed props map has to be of this type:

```
Map<QName,Serializable> props = new Map<QName,Serializable>();
```

Then supposing your namespace in model is `http://www.custommodel.com/kb/1.0` you should do:

```
props.put(new QName("http://www.custommodel.com/kb/1.0","documentRef"), "123");
props.put(new QName("http://www.custommodel.com/kb/1.0","documentID"), "1234");
```

Or, better, you could write your convenient interface:

```
public interface MyModel {
   KB_DOCUMENT_REF = new QName("http://www.custommodel.com/kb/1.0","documentRef");
}
```

Then, much clearer:

```
props.put(MyModel.KB_DOCUMENT_REF, "123");
```